# ¿Por qué no me imprime la información del objeto?

Tags: java

sucede que quiero imprimir en pantalla estos datos los cuales se encuentran en el método tostring.

```
public String tostring() {
    return "the weight is :"+ this.getWeight() +" and my age is :"+ this.getAge();
}
```

pero me lo imprime de esta forma

```
ejercicio2.Ejercicio2@15db9742
```

aquí el código con los set y get

```
public class Ejercicio2 {
private int weight;
private int age;

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

y la clase main

```
public class Usoejercicio2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ejercicio2 ob1 = new Ejercicio2();

    ob1.setAge(21);
    ob1.setWeight(55);

    System.out.println(ob1);
```

que estoy haciendo mal? si por favor me corrigen

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudastes

Comment: El método que desea sobreescribir es `toString()` con la **S** maýuscula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Por qué no me imprime la información del objeto?

El problema radica en la forma como has escrito el nombre de este método:

```java
public String tostring() {
    return "the weight is :"+ this.getWeight() +" and my age is :"+ this.getAge();
}
```

Si hubieras usado la anotación `@Override`, el compilador hubiera dado un error de compilación y esto se debe porque `tostring()` no es un método heredado de la clase `Object` (clase base de todas las clases en Java), por lo tanto, no se puede sobrescribir.

**Ejemplo del error:**

```java
class A 
{
    @Override 
    public String tostring() {
       return "the weight is :"+ this.getWeight() +" and my age is :"+ this.getAge();
    }
}
```

Al compilar muestra el siguiente error:

```java
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

El error significa que no puedes sobrescribir el método porque no hay una clase base que lo tenga implementado.

El método que hereda todas las clases (porque por defecto son subclases de `Object`) se llama `toString` y no `tostring`. Así que la **solución** es cambiarle el nombre:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "the weight is :"+ this.getWeight() +" and my age is :"+ this.getAge();
}
```

Y listo, el programa debería de lanzar el resultado esperado.

También **recalco** que esta sentencia:

```java
System.out.println(ob1);
```

Es equivalente a:

```java
System.out.println(ob1.toString());
```

La diferencia es que la primera sentencia, el compilador de Java implícitamente invoca al método `toString()` y en la segunda la agregamos manualmente. Así que da igual cual uses, porque ambas darán el mismo resultado.

**Conclusión:**

Usa la anotación `@Override`, ahorra dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Un motivo de cierre de las preguntas es "contiene errores tipográficos".